# Any way to get MAC address from local network devices on android using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

having studied quite a lot of links, I realized that Google and Apple have blocked some methods (ARP, etc.) for obtaining a MAC address.

But how can this be done now, while studying Google play, I came across several applications that still receive MAC addresses on android 13.

How can this be done?

I looked through a lot of information but did not find anything working.

Answer (score 0):

I also checked some Android network app and they actually do their own ARP calls (ie not depending on the IOS arp cache).

But not sure you can implement such low level networking in Flutter. There might also be another loophole that Fing uses (can't see any ARP calls from them) but they might very well be removed in future Android releases

Comment: Yes, I also looked at Fing and another application (I don’t remember the name already) receives MAC without any problems.

I wrote to the developer of the second application. He will answer me that he uses netlink socket. But I still don't know how to implement it :)

Maybe this will help you somehow

Comment: Might very well do! Will investigate!

Comment: If you can figure out how to do it. Please share the results here, it will be interesting to see